# How do Stack Overflow moderators keep track of all posted comments? What tools/technologies are used?

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-tools

I want to know how Stack Overflow (SO) moderators keep track on comments and answers posted over thousands or more questions round the clock.

Also, as mentioned on https://stackexchange.com/sites, there are around 5.4 millions of users and 11 million questions on SO. So, considering this, there would be a **flood of comments** on large number of questions at once.

How do Stack Overflow moderators or the system **manage these things internally**, and that too without any performance issues?

Looking at http://area51.stackexchange.com/, I guess they are using bots, and yes obviously they should. But, what they are using at backend to handle these much **traffic** and **load** on their system.

References:

- *[How does the Stack Overflow questions-and-answers system work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15866403/how-stackoverflow-questions-answers-system-works)*
- *[Help us figure out a way to handle the explosion of comments on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/180325/help-us-figure-out-a-way-to-handle-the-explosion-of-comments-on-stack-overflow)*

This might be a repetitive question here, but after searching a bit, I still haven't found my answers.

Comment: You seem to assume that every answer and every comment is viewed by the elected (diamond) moderators. I suggest reading about [The Theory of Moderation](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/) for some background on what their role actually is.

Comment: Awesome blog.. it indeed clarifies the moderation activity on SO.

Comment: Why is it down voted? Have I missed anything here?

Or is it for instance to show how moderation works....

Comment: First time on meta? http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta - I assume people are downvoting because of the assumption of how moderation works (i.e. not thinking at all about the community moderation aspects of the sites)

Comment: Yes.. its my first time here. Thanks for your thoughts on this. I didn't even have an idea that there will be a different 'meta' like site, which is again exact replica of SO.

Comment: and don't worry about the down votes on meta. They don't count towards your reputation.

Comment: but cleary, take into account things that you don't see (harder to do than to tell ^^), like the already mentioned review queues, community-based. Apart from that, some users may have created their own small tools / scripts to automate a part of the work, or some spreadsheets library of "ready-made" texts (like "Welcome to Stack Overflow, please see the [tour], blahblah"....), and the tailored made moderation tools that the site is made of (mostly based on jquery ? ;) )

Answer (score 9):

Our elected moderators are the exception handlers, they only look at and act on posts that the community cannot handle with their own moderation tools.

So to answer your questions: They do not. The vast majority of moderation activities on SO is performed by the users.

Comment: Great! But, which tools/technologies are used internally to notify these users/moderators about new comments/flag or other activities?

Comment: @manoj we have review queues (where review tasks are automatically created for specific raised flags for instance) and users can moderate (edit, vote on, vote to close, comment) on posts they come across. The diamond mods also have a flag queue.

Comment: So, I think SO developers have designed such systems to handle these queues and notifications to users. But, which technology stack they are using at backend for such improved performance?

Comment: @manoj http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-are-used-to-build-the-stack-exchange-network

Comment: Thanks.. thats exactly I was looking for.

Comment: @manoj FYI it was the first Google hit for *"stack exchange tech stack"* - basic research is expected on Meta, too.

Comment: Meh - why can I not catch all mine before they bubble up?